# Has such a variant of the Möbius function been used in sieve methods?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let  $ S $ be a finite subset of the primes and let  $ \mu_{S} $ the multiplicative arithmetic function defined by  $ \mu_{S}(p)=-1_{p\not\in S} $ for all prime  $ p $. Has any such mock Möbius function been used in sieve methods ? My idea is that it can be useful if  $ S $ is adapted to fit the considered problem.

One can also consider the case  $ \mu_{S,\chi} $ for some Dirichlet character  $ \chi $ such that  $ \mu_{S,\chi}(p)=\mu_{S}(p)-\chi(p).1_{p\in S} $.